# Accessing a specific element on IPC shared memory

Tags: c, ipc, shared-memory

I'm reading about shared memory, and a question popped up in my head - since the signature of shmget is `int shmget(key_t key, size_t size,int shmflg)` then we can allocate for example a shared memory of 30 integers by passing `30*sizeof(int)` as argument to shmget, so my question is can we access an nth element of that shared memory ? (can we access the 4th integer of our shared memory for example?)

Comment: [void *shmat(int shmid, const void *shmaddr,
int shmflg);](https://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat)

Comment: "*can we access an nth element of that shared memory*" in terms of addressing access to SHM is not different from accessing local memory.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you access it like you would do with a normal pointer ? For instance :

```
int shmid = shmget(key, 30 * sizeof(int), 0644 | IPC_CREATE);
void* data = shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);
int element = *((int *)data + 3);
```

Comment: `*((int *)data + 3)`?  If the shared memory is really an `int[30]`, declaring `data` as an `int *` and accessing the fourth element as `data[3]` is a lot simpler.